# VBA export to text file gives an extra empty line

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an extra line at the export. I red in another post about adding ; to prevent exporting an empty line but it didn't even what to run the script with that. Below is my script. Any idea how to solve that? Thanks!

```
For i = 9 To endRow
    output = Cells(i, textOneDATAcol).Text & "^" & Cells(i, textTwoDATAcol).Text
Next i
```

Comment: Can you post your whole `Sub`? How do you try 'exporting' it?

Comment: gosh...thank you so much for asking...that actually solved my problem...    Open FileName For Output As #1
    Print #1, output;

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 9 To endRow
    output = Cells(i, textOneDATAcol).Text & "^" & Cells(i, textTwoDATAcol).Text
Next i

Open FileName For Output As #1
    Print #1, output;
Close #1
```

sorry for the messy code layout..I really don't know how to make it work...but this is how I was able to get rid of the extra empty line. Just adding output;